# this new method of verifying

Tags: restrictive-clauses, post-modifier

1. I like the new method of verifying what everyone says twice.
2. I like this new method of verifying what everyone says twice.

Do those mean

a. There was an old method of verifying what everyone said twice. I like the new one.

or

b. The method of verifying what everyone says twice is new and I like it. We didn't use to verify what everyone said twice.

Many thanks

Comment: They could mean (a) or (b), and also there is no definite implication that there was any older method of verifying, whether once, twice, or at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is not given what the old method was, nor even if there was an old method.

There might have been an old method of verifying what people said twice, or the old method might have verified what people said only once... or three times.   Or the old method might not have verified what people said at all.

You might infer that the new method is being implicitly compared to something. So you would suppose that there was probably something to compare it to.  That is there was probably some kind of old method. Moreover the speaker is assuming that you know what the new method is being compared to.

So in any practical situation there would be no ambiguity.  Not because the sentence tells if you used to verify everything twice, but because you knew the answer to that before the speaker even opened their mouth.

Answer (score 0):

- Use '**this**' when something is immediately in front of you in a physical sense, or something that you have just considered, or are currently experiencing.
- Use '**that**' when indicating toward something that is more distant in a physical sense, or a thing or event that has passed by.
- Use the definite article '**the**' when referring to something unique that is known to or immediately recognisable by your audience.

So, in your specific examples, "*the* new method" would be one that whoever you are talking to already knows about. Use "*this* new method" if you are currently discussing, using, or examining a new method together.